# ckeditor file upload setup

Tags: file-upload, ckeditor

I can`t figure this problem out by myself, so maybe someone already done similar job here.

The problem is that i can upload file. But it append in IFRAME after image field.

The demo is here: http://myprtf.com/test/codes/ckeditor_showtime/

I want to make it work just like in a demo [here](http://ckeditor.com/demo)

If someone could help me with that, I think this guide will help everyone who facing setup of ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select "right" under "alignment" in the image properties (right-click). You can also set this when you're adding an image.

Comment: The thing is that I want to upload files just like in ckeditor demo. Not align them

Comment: I see. I tried to upload a random image and it uploads correctly but you have not configured the folder where you're displaying it from correctly. It should be:
http://myprtf.com/test/codes/ckeditor_showtime/images/
while when you upload it displays:
http://myprtf.com/test/codes/ckeditor_showtime/index.php/upload/images/
There should be a variable in the configuration for the upload folder, check that out and see which one of the paths it matches.